# Props are not passing from parent to child components in React Functional component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi developers I'm just a beginner in React.js. I tried to print props by passing from parent to child.

This is app.js file

```
    import React from "react";
    import Hooks from "./components/ReactHooks1";
    import Hooks2 from "./components/ReactHooks2";
    
    const App = () => {
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>
                Welcome to React App
            </h1>
            <Hooks2 title2={"Welcome"}/>
            </div>
    
        )
    }
    
    export default App
```

This is child component file

```
import React from 'react';


const Hooks2 = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
}


export default Hooks2;
```

I just try to print props but it shows an empty object. what am I doing wrong please help me on this

Comment: Add `return null` to the child component.

Answer (score 2):

You should return something or null to parent component from child, when you're using it in parent component. This will solve your problem

```
export const Hooks2 = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return <></>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rasith

Not sure why would you want to do this, but if you're trying to pass a child component that would print something to the console. In this case you need to **destructure the component's props**. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) an article about it from MDN.

This is how I would do it:

```js
const CustomComponent = ({title}) => {
  console.log(title)
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <CustomComponent title={"Welcome"}/>
    </>
  );
};
```

For the title to be printed to the console, no need to add a return statement to the child component. Again, not sure why you would do this, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Well trying to console.log title certainly would not work because what you are passing is called title2. Also your child component is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to return anything from your child component( even a fragment )

You can access title2 in the child component with any of these methods:

1- using props object itself

```js
const Hooks2 = (props) => {
    
    console.log(props.title2);
    
    return;
}
```

2- you can also destructure props in place to access title2 directly

```js
const Hooks2 = ({title2}) => {

    console.log(title2);
    
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use destructuring in your ChildComponent, to grab your props directly by name:

```
const Hooks2 = ({title2}) => {
    console.log(title2);
}
```

You can read a little bit more about it in here: https://www.amitmerchant.com/always-destructure-your-component-props-in-react/